# Converting NSData to NSUrl nil string parameter

Tags: ios

I am trying to convert NSdata to NSUrl, and I found this method on the internet:

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    [session sendResourceAtURL:url withName:@"Resource" toPeer:peerID withCompletionHandler:nil];
```

Seems all right to me, but the app crashes at the second line and gives the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initWithString:relativeToURL:]: nil string parameter'
```

Can't get why...

Comment: From where comes myData? myData is UTF8 compilant?

Comment: Mydata comes from myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dict];

Comment: Could you log the NSString contents before trying to create an NSURL instance? It'll make it easier to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myData is not UTF-8 encoded.

From the NSString docs:

> Returns nil if the initialization fails for some reason (for example
>   if data does not represent valid data for encoding).

You should always check for this type of condition...

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url;
if (urlString) {
     url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
} else {
    // handle failure
}
```

Additionally, make sure you're using UTF8 encoding when you create the `myData` object, or switch from `NSUTF8StringEncoding` to the correct encoding type.

Comment: This is myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dict];

Answer (score 0):

If dict from [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dict] is NSDictionary class then you must extract the urlString from that dictionary.

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData  options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSString *urlString = [dictionary valueForKey:@"url"];
```

Comment: It's not an `NSDictionary`, it's simply `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

change the encoding, say to NSUTF16StringEncoding

Answer (score 0):

your String returns null try these method

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@".png"];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:myData attributes:nil];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath])

{

    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath isDirectory:NO];
}
```